# How many equilateral triangles of side 1 are there in an irregular hexagon?

Tags: geometry, triangles

As the question states, given a hexagon whose sides are not necessarily equal, but all the angles of this hexagon are equal to 120 degrees, how many equilateral triangles of side 1 can fit inside that hexagon?

Please, refer to the pictures for clarification.

[Hexagon with 6 triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVLxP.png)

[Hexagon with 13 triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoQor.png)

Comment: How would you deal with cases when there is no exact fit?

Comment: @Andrei assume that the given lengths will always result in a hexagon in which the triangles will be an exact fit. PS: given the fact that all the angles are 120 degrees, is there any pattern of lengths for the hexagon(e.g. alternating between 1 and 2 (1,2,1,2,1,2) ) for the triangles to fit perfectly?

Comment: to be exact: in what conditions (lengths-wise) is the resulting hexagon perfect for an integer number of equilateral triangles to fit in?

Comment: The sides have to be integer lengths. Then you can completely fill with equilateral triangles.